# Orchard - Warnings for "Second level Cache"

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I get the following type of warning repeatedly in the orchard log files

```
WARN Second-level cache is enabled in a class, but no cache provider was selected. Fake cache used.
```

This rather floods the logs when set to warn. So two questions:

Ho

1. w do I get rid of this warning? It implies I should be implementing
   something, but this looks like low level Orchard/NHibernate
   internals. Should this not be working "out of the box"
2. Does this cause a performance issue if not resolved?

cheers

Comment: You should probably enable SysCache.

Comment: Thanks, but we have this enabled and we still get the problem

Comment: Never seen that. Summoning Sébastien.